# Why is this true: $(4+t^2)\frac{dy}{dt}+2ty= \frac{d}{dt}[(4+t^2)y]$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm looking at a solution to a problem in my textbook and one of the steps is giving me issues. It states that:

$(4+t^2)\frac{dy}{dt}+2ty= \frac{d}{dt}[(4+t^2)y]$

Can anyone explain how this is true? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **product rule**.

$((4+t^2)y)' = (4+t^2)' y + (4+t^2) y'$